# unless VS. till/until

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, conditional-constructions

> - You're not going out, 'till you've finished your task.
> - You're not going out, unless you've finished your task.
> - You're not going out, unless you **finish** your task.

I made atypo and correct the bold part above: I changed finished to finish.

Would you tell me if all the sentences are correct and whether or not they would mean the same thing?

**Furthermore**:

***UPDATED***: I am wondering we must use unless woth which of the conditional sentences?

I meant by which one of these? the firs conditional type, the second one, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need for `'` next to *till*. *Till* is an older word than *until* and is not an abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

All three sentences are acceptable. Though Sentence 2 is preferred in common usage to Sentence 3, they convey the same essential meaning. I will focus on the differences between Sentences 1 and 2.

"Till" (or "until") is time-related and is roughly equivalent in meaning to "up to/ending at a (stated) point in time." In a [**conditional**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence) or negative statement (i.e. "not until"), it can be substituted by "(only) **when/after**" and implies the speaker's expectation or relative *certainty* that a necessary action will be performed (or a necessary event will occur) at some time in the future.

For example:

Breakfast will be served **until** 10:00 a.m. (unconditional, simply time-related)
The room will **not** be available **until** it has been cleaned. (negative/conditional, time-related) -->The room will **(only)** be available **after** it has been cleaned.

"Not...unless" is more "purely" conditional (not implying any relationship to time) and its meaning can be substituted by "only **if**." The negative element of the sentence is either expressed in the clause containing the consequence (result) or implied in the clause containing the condition (requirement). Compared with "until," the speaker is showing *uncertainty* that a necessary action will be performed (or a necessary event will occur).

For example:

I will **not** go to the party **unless** you do.  (negative/conditional) --> I will go to the party **only if** you do.
I will throw away the milk **unless** you ask me to save it. (implied negative/conditional) --> I will throw away the milk **if** you do **not** ask me to save it.